# Solution for NLP using Viterbi algorithm

Tags: nlp

Hand simulate the Viterbi algorithm using the data and probability estimates in Figures 6.4 - 6.6 on the sentence Flower flowers like flowers. Draw transition network as in Figure 6.10 - 6.12 for the problem, and identify what part of speech the algorithm identifies for each.

[Figure 6.4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wvHYl.png)

[Figure 6.5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMag1.png)

[Figure 6.6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZhkUx.png)

[Figure 6.10](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtI5r.png)

[Figure 6.11](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTVms.png)

[Figure 6.12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcgnJ.png)

I'm an newbie and learning about NLP. I can't understand and how to solve this exercise. Please help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: Refer this: https://phontron.com/slides/nlp-programming-en-04-hmm.pdf